# Need help about WebView in localhost

Tags: android, localhost

I want to if it possible to use webview in localhost, without using Internet to do a test.
And i want to know too how get automatically pages of web site in you app like facebook app.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: android localhost is 10.0.2.2, hth

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html"); //for asset html files
```

or

```
webView.loadUrl("content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/demo.html"); //for sdcard html files
```

and your app need the internet access permision

Answer (score 0):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from Here's [a link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Thanks you, if for example in my website there are 2 menus like this
1-Menu1
  -subMenu1
  -subMenu2
2-Menu2
  -subMenu1
  -subMenu2
and if my domain name is : http://www.mysite.com
How explore all menus automatically in my app with webViw or or others methods.

thank you